# Realm database - how do I structure my Android application

Tags: android, design-patterns, realm

I have an application where I want to search for a book using ISBN and display it on the screen. The `Book` objects are stored in a Realm database with ISBN as primary key. If they are not stored in the database, they are retrieved asynchronously (ASyncTask) from a server and then stored in the database.

Now, I am unfamiliar with Realm and how to use it.

In the code below, would `ViewBookActivity` and `MainController` run on the same thread, and therefore use the same database instance? Would returning a Realm object from a "static class" be a problem?

How can I guarantee that calling `MainController.getBook()` always returns a book? The way it works now, is that when getBook is called and the book is not in the database, it returns null.

Is a changelisteners in each Activity that uses the MainController the only way? I want to avoid, if possible, to use/reference Realm at all in the activities and make them get objects through the MainController instead.

```
public class RealmActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration); // Clean slate
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default
    }

    @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

public class ViewBookActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ISBN = intent.getStringExtra("ISBN");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_result);
        setBook(ISBN);
    }

    public void setBook(String ISBN) {
        Book b = MainController.getBook(ISBN);
        // Display book on screen
    }
}

public class MainController {
    static Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    public static Book getBook(String isbn) {
        Book book = realm.where(Book.class)
                .equalTo("isbn", isbn)
                .findFirst();
        if (book == null) {
            NetworkController.getBook(isbn);
        } else {
            return book;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class NetworkController {
    private static BookHandler bookHandler = new BookHandler();
    public static void getBook(String isbn) {
        NetworkHelper.sendRequest(HTTPRequestMethod.GET,
                "/books/" + isbn, bookHandler);
    }
}


public class NetworkHelper {
    private static String host = "http://crowdshelf-dev.herokuapp.com";
    public static void sendRequest(final HTTPRequestMethod requestMethod, final String route, final ResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(host + "/api" + route);
                    Log.d("NETDBTEST", "NetworkHelper request: " + requestMethod.toString() + " URL: " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    String jsonString = builder.toString();
                    responseHandler.handleJsonResponse(jsonString);
                return null;
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}

public class BookHandler implements ResponseHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleJsonResponse(String jsonString) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Book.class, jsonString);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
}

public class Book extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String isbn;
    // Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First, I don't know why you created `RealmActivity` just for cleaning database. Activities are for showing UI. If it doesn't have any purpose then move the code to some other class. Like you can create a new class `RealmHandler` and keep this kind of code there.

2) You don't really need to create a static function to get Realm object. You could have your `MainController` function like this:

```
    public class MainController {


    public Book getBook(String isbn, Context context) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(context);

        Book book = realm.where(Book.class)
                .equalTo("isbn", isbn)
                .findFirst();
        if (book == null) {
            NetworkController.getBook(isbn);
        } else {
            return book;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3)

> How can I guarantee that calling MainController.getBook() always
>   returns a book?

You can't guarantee that you always get a Book, for example a Book isn't found on server, or there's no internet connection. You have to handle that case manually.

`sendBook` function calls `AsyncTask` and `AsyncTask` runs on a separate thread so you can't return your server results when you call  `NetworkController.getBook(isbn)`. The only way to get results is in `BookHandler. handleJsonResponse`

By the way, you don't need to implement Handler to get results from `AsyncTask`. You can override `onPostExecution` function to get control of your results and perform UI on Main thread.

Solution: 
You can handle this in different ways as you like, here's one of the way:

i) Call `MainController.getBook()` to get a book. If Book isn't found then run `NetworkController.getBook(isbn);` - This will run on a different Thread and current Thread will send back null to your Activity. If null then you just ignore it or perform action accordingly.

ii) In `AsyncTask` you could first show a ProgressBar to tell user something is in Process while you are getting data from Server. You could do this in `onPreExecution` function of `AsyncTask`.

iii) Get results in `onPostExecution` function of `AsyncTask`. Now you are back on your main thread. You can directly update your UI if you are in the same Activity, but in your case you are not. You can't directly return data like in a function or update UI.

iv) You can send a signal to your MainActivity that network call has finished and new data is in the database so update view. You can could use Event bus for this purpose. I personally use Otto by Square: http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: iii) iv) Can I use Event Bus or Otto in the `BookHandler` with a listener in `ViewBookActivity` to update UI? I want to keep my `BookHandler` as I have many handlers which works differently and I don't want all that code mashed together in `onPostExecution`.